# 400 Bad Request on apt update using old official cloud images

Tags: apt, updates, cloud

I'm running several instances of Ubuntu 18.04 using an official cloud image downloaded from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/ on May 2019.

Everything worked fine until last week. Now, all my instances can't update, because the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is pointing to `http://user_zone.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` which is not working (400 Bad Request).

Looks like some server-side change at some point broke that URL. Unfortunately, it looks like newer images are using `http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/` instead, so I'm afraid they won't spot the problem soon.

Removing the underscore in the URL fixes the issue. So changing the URL in all the instances should work as a workaround, but it's a lot of trouble in my scenario.

Should I file a bug report to ubuntu.com? How to do so? Every guide to file bug reports are referring to particular software problems, new features, etc. and I think I might be off-track on this.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using that image in several instances and I can't just update it.That URL worked like a week ago, so it might be some server-side change that is breaking this.

Comment: You're right, thank you. I've just edited the question.

Comment: I would file the bug against the 'clout-init' pckage, so the triager or developer can link the bug to an internal Canonical IT request to restore the subdomain and forward it to the new location.